# useSWR successfully fetches , but data returns undefined

Tags: next.js, axios, fetch, next-auth, swr

I am using useSWR hook to fetch and display a data from an API.

the code is :

```
const backendURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL;
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  let userToken = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status == "authenticated") {
      console.log(status);
      userToken = session.user.accessToken;
      console.log(session.user.accessToken);
    }
  }, [session, status]);

  const fetcher = (url) => {
    axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${session.user.accessToken}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };

  const { data, error, isLoading, isValidating } = useSWR(
    `${backendURL}/content/get_all/content_type`,
    fetcher,
    { refreshInterval: 1000 }
  );
```

when i console log the response in `.then()` function like

```
.then((res) => console.log(res))
```

it console.logs the response, and in also network section I can see that data is fetched succesfully.

but when i add `console.log(data)` it is always undefined.

How can i solve this?

my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^6.5.1",
    "antd": "^4.23.4",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "cookies-next": "^2.1.1",
    "less": "^4.1.3",
    "next": "^12.2.5",
    "next-auth": "^4.18.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-calendar": "^4.0.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "swr": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.7.23",
    "@types/react": "18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.6",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.12",
    "eslint": "8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.1.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.17",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
```

Comment: That might be because data (as returned from the useSWR function) is only available in the next 'tick' and not immediately when the axios function returns. If you render it out on the page using {JSON.stringify(data)} you should see it rendered out. Or does it not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to return the axios in the fetcher callback

```
const fetcher = (url) => {
return axios
  .get(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${session.user.accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err)); 
};
```

or remove the curly braces

```
const fetcher = (url) => axios
  .get(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${session.user.accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })
  .then((res) => {
    return res;
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Just a formatting improvement for the answer: Can you fix the first code snippet so that it includes the closing curly brace?

Comment: Thank you so much @furkotikoo , how i missed it ..

Comment: @Somebody i have tried several ways but the closing curly brace keeps standing outside.. Ekim Cem Ülger you are welcome brom

Comment: There are just some missing spaces berfore the brace

Comment: @Somebody thank you man, i have deleted spaces until get the brace on the catch(...); line
´.catch((err) => console.log(err)); };´ 
then **shift + enter** put the brace on new line in the code block.

Answer (score -2):

```
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res); // console.log returns undefined.
  return res;
})
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].